# Google Trends with web browser control

Tags: webbrowser-control

If I navigate to http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=lg%2C%20nokia google trends url, the web browser control shows the TIMESERIES graph properly. But if I copy and paste the script tag provided in the same url, it shows a JavaScript error. I have copied the following script block from Google Trends web site to my web browser control html design.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/trends/embed.js?hl=en-AU&q=lg,+nokia&content=1&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=5&w=500&h=330"></script>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about potential bugs in external software.